# Unable to find amazon pay permission for my alexa skill in alexa web console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-pay

I have created a alexa skill and also enabled amazon pay in the skill. When my colleague from USA tries to purchase the product from skill, he is allowed to use amazon pay. he just have to enable permission of amazon pay in alexa web console. 
However when I try to access the same from my India location, it is not showing me any option of enabling amazon pay in alexa web console.
It is showing me other permission, but amazon pay is not visible.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can offer paid skills in the following languages and locales:

```
Languages – English (US), Spanish (US)
Locales – en_US, es_US
```

You can offer paid skills in the following marketplaces.
Amazon.com

Please check the next link for more information: https://developer.amazon.com/ja-JP/docs/alexa/paid-skills/overview.html